# Saving a Ton of Data for a Game

Tags: c++, database, file-io

So I'm designing a 2D game in C++ with tons of data-- basically, it features randomly generated, blocky terrain (in the form of a very large byte array), much in the style of Terraria, and will also need to save state for monsters (among other various game objects).  As the player runs around, sections of the game world will be loaded/saved to the disk, making for an infinitely expanding game world (similar to Minecraft).

What's my best option for saving everything to the disk?  I'm mostly concerned with efficiency (so the user never has to wait on content to load), but ease of use and maintainability are a close second.  I'm very familiar with Minecraft's method of saving, which has a separate file for each "Chunk", but I was wondering-- should I designate my own files like Minecraft, or go with a database?  What other possibilities are out there?  If I use a file, would I get a significant performance boost by asking the OS for raw access and handling that myself (much like a database does)?

Also, I'd like to be able to port the project from PC to Mac and console-- alternatives for individual platforms are fine, I'll just have to swap methods depending on the platform.

Thanks!

Comment: This is probably a better question for [gamedev.se](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single file would be much cleaner and could take less physical disk space than relying on the filesystem for organization. Just maintain a table of offsets at the beginning of the file to link to each of the chunks.

As far as compression, applying a run length encoding would definitely deflate the file size, and if it is like Minecraft, you'll have a lot of identical blocks in sequence. As a bonus, it will load faster on computers using platter drives, as a couple of bytes can equate to thousands of blocks, instead of having to read a byte for each of those blocks. Here's a quick tip for an effective run length encoding: use a command byte, say 0x00. All other bytes are associated with a block, but the command byte would signify a non-block bit of info. The traditional run length encoding looks like this:

```
Source: AAAABBBBBBBCDDDEFA
Destination: 0x0441074201430344014501460161
Plaintext: .A.B.C.D.E.F.A
```

Using a command byte, omitting sequences that would increase size:

```
Source: AAAABBBBBBBCDDDEFA
Destination: 0x00044100074243444444454641.
Plaintext: ..A..BCDDDEFA
```

This has a distinct advantage in "marbled" sections of data.

One other thing, I recommend that you use a system for storing numbers similar to the midi format, although in little endian format. To save you the googling, all it really means is that you sacrifice a bit for each byte you use to store the number. If the 8th bit is set, it means there's another byte in the number, and it cascades. Example:

```
Storing: 65
Stored as: 0x41 (01000001) //The eighth bit is not set, so this number only occupies 7 bits.

Storing: 192
Stored as: 0xC081 (11000000 10000001) //The eighth bit of the first byte is set, so the following byte is part of the number. The second byte doesn't have the eighth bit set, so the number ends there.

Storing: 612453
Stored as: 0x72D825 (11100101 1011000 00100101) //The eighth bit of the first two bytes are set, and the third is not, so this number occupies 3 bytes.
```

I hope that I helped provide some insight.

Comment: Awesome, this is really useful.  I've never messed with encoding before, but I understand the basics.  I'll have to do a little googling on it, as well as platter drives.  I'll probably use the MIDI-style encoding for "special" blocks (like TileEntities in Minecraft-- say I want a chest that holds items).  Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I used to store numbers in a format that stored the length of the numbers using an extra byte. It's simpler, but for numbers that occupy 7 bytes or less, it's not as efficient, and I never use numbers bigger than 4 bytes. When I looked up the midi format, I was pleased by this ingenious way to store variable length numbers. I'm glad I helped :)

Comment: As for the single file thing, I would have to rely on my OS skills... if my chunks are variable size on disk, copying due to external fragmentation would be awful... perhaps a paging system with an index at the beginning of the file?  What if I have to page the paging index??  *faints*

Comment: That's true, you'd have to defragment on writes, which wouldn't be very optimal. In this case, yes, the most pain free way would be to use the host filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of a database is to speed up complex searches. You don't have any searching going on; you have a block of data that you need to get into memory. Databases will be of absolutely no value to you for this task.

What you need really depends on how much data you're talking about and how platform-specific you want to be. You seem to be talking about a 2D game, so the chunks can't be *that* big. Regular C or C++ file IO functions would probably be good enough. Worst-case, you might have to stick them in a thread for async file IO and processing.

Really, just start doing the obvious thing. If it becomes a problem, try to make it asynchronous with simple threading constructs. You probably shouldn't need to go too much farther than that.

Comment: Hmm, alright, no to databases then.  Ehhhh the chunk size is variable, but the larger they are the faster other things will be (hard to explain).  They're currently 1024x1024 (a whopping 1 MB), but 512x512 and 256x256 are definitely options.

Comment: i'll tell you when 1mb was whooping...

Comment: @Philip: If you're talking about 1MB chunks, you really don't need to do much special at all. Just load them and process them. Again, use a thread if responsiveness is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, it really depends on a lot of factors.  My group had a system of saving hundreds or even thousands of files to a database, and performance improved.  Those files were small, so the reading and writing were short compared to the latency of waiting for the disk drive to spin up, or for the OS to navigate the file system to each individual file.

If you have thousands of files smaller than a 4 kB page, I'd go with a database.  If files are bigger than that, then go with files.  A database won't help your throughput -- only your latency.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't thinking about disk latency.  I might wind up with a database then, depending.  Could a database *hurt* my throughput?

Comment: You could get the same advantage by sticking those loose files in a TAR or Zip file.

Comment: The disadvantage with a tar or zip is that you have to read the whole thing.  He says he only wants to read part of the data into memory at a time.  So I wouldn't go with a single file -- the operating system has to load up the whole thing and keep it in its disk cache.

Comment: I don't think a database will hurt your throughput.  Once you get that first byte, it should be at least as fast as doing it yourself through the file system.

Comment: I thought if the OS has paging, it would load only the pages of the file it needed, then cache them?  Don't know if consoles page, though.  As for zip/tar, I suppose the whole file would have to be unpacked, which would be slow.  I was thinking I might use a single file and have my own encoding.

Comment: @danimator: "The disadvantage with a tar or zip is that you have to read the whole thing." That's not true at all. You need to read the directory, but you can pick and choose which files you want to extract without touching the others. When I say "tar", I mean **tar**, not "tar.gz".